# How to prevent termination until SIGTERM and SIGINT?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, signals

I am having trouble understanding how to ignore all signals except for a handful.

```
  // My attempt in C
  struct sigaction action;
  action.sa_handler = myhandler;
  sigfillset(&(action.sa_mask));
  sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);
```

This works in the sense that it calls myhandler() when any signal is raised, however, the process is killed when sending for instance the SIGQUIT signal.

How do I go about ignoring all signals except for these two?

Comment: Generally speaking you would mask out those signals you don't wish to receive (as by [`pthread_sigmask`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html)), or would set their [disposition to SIG_IGN](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) (that is, to "ignore").

Comment: I came across that while looking on StackOverflow, but couldn't seem to figure out how to use them properly.

Comment: May I suggest you try, and post a minimal, compilable, complete example that demonstrates what is or isn't working.